# filecoin "mineOne: unexpectedly nil MiningBaseInfo"

Tags: go, filecoin, filecoin-lotus

I have lotus miner running and it gives me this error in `/var/log/lotus/miner.log` over and over

```
{"level":"warn","ts":"2021-05-14T13:55:06.402Z","logger":"miner","caller":"miner/miner.go:429","msg":"mineOne: unexpectedly nil MiningBaseInfo for round 75647, off tipset 756470/{afy2bzacedp3fzzkvaytpl5x7orc6k7hnc5qzxq7ysnv6eh2gdjfnpyaz4xhi,bafy2bzacedolwxteui23vrhv3h6yf5wsqkz4mivdhm354uk3i7imzuetd6qii,afy2bzacedk6r2xor55wrhpix2ccur6rqjl6wr3kkqxojb55cd4zz6kxbsazk,bafy2bzacebmjtbbcxznogp5mz2gekjbleznxtczs3qwjjoxinpyhyq4qhrhdy,bafy2bzacedukqxt7xdj5ln6x2lezawhqyb4ntcbxqr6b43cn4s43o6exreobo}"}
```

- lotus version 1.11.0-dev+mainnet+git.bf10b051f
- lotus-miner version 1.11.0-dev+mainnet+git.bf10b051f
- lotus-worker version 1.11.0-dev+mainnet+git.bf10b051f

Comment: I think this error needs to be reported to the dev team, there is unexpected nil here.

Comment: Refer: https://github.com/filecoin-project/lotus/issues/6260